# C# does not contain a definition for 'Content'

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I created a service which accept user inputs as xml and if any parameters is missing a view must me returned which allows user to enter the missing details.

So i thought it is impossible to return view using api controller so i used mvc controller. But the following error is shown when i read xml.

> C# does not contain a definition for 'Content' and no extension method 'Content' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is my code

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
   public IHttpActionResult MyService([FromUri] TestProperty testProperty)
    {
       string DataXML = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

My questions are

1.How to solve this error?

2.Is there any other ways to accomplish my need using api controller? Returning view to user and accept xml.

Comment: do you have `System.Web` & `System.Net.Http` assembly added in your project ?

Comment: Yes i have added both @PranavSingh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please note that, `Content` is available in `HttpRequestMessage` of `ApiController` not in the `HttpRequestBase` of `Controller`

If you want to use `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` your controller should be inherited from `ApiController` (Web API) not with the Controller.

If you want to read the content in MVC controller, you can try like following.

```
string content = "";
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
 using (var reader = new StreamReader(
          Request.InputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 4096, true))
      {
         content = reader.ReadToEnd();
      }
 //Reset the stream
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
```